# I keep getting an error that the permission to the output file is denied and so my code can't run

Tags: c++, windows, permissions, directory

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        ifstream fin("problema24.in");
        ofstream fout("problema24.out");
        int n, i;
        float v[1000];
        fin>>n;
        for(i=1;i<=2*n;i++)
        {
            fin>>v[i];
        }
        fin.close();
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            v[i]=floor(v[i])+v[n*2-i+1]-floor(v[n*2-i+1]);
        }
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            fout<<setprecision(3)<<v[i]<<" ";
        }
        fout.close();
        return 0;
}
```

// I keep getting this message:

> ld.exe||cannot open output file bin\Debug\problema 24.exe Permission
>   denied|

Can you guys help me please!!

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused, if the linker cannot create a new binary named "bin\Debug\problema 24.exe" because it is currently running. Make sure that executable is not running so that the linker can rebuild it.

Comment: Note that's specific for windows environments apparently. I don't have such behavior on my linux development environment.

Comment: Yes I have noticed this as well. Linux will let you run multiple instances after recompiling.

Comment: In general windows will not let me do alot of things that linux does. Windows is very particular in the "right way" to do things it seems. Another example is how in linux I can link a library built without debug symbols to a program that is built with debug symbols and run debug on it. Windows will not let you do this which is very annoying. By windows I should clarify that I mean Visual Studio